# ng-grid how to enable Edit and Delete buttons

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am still new to Angular and learning about the ngGrid.
I have a basic ng-grid with some data on schedules. I have Add, Edit and Delete buttons at the bottom of the grid.

I want to disable the Edit and Delete buttons by default when the grid is loaded.

I would like to enable those buttons when any row from the ng-grid is selected.

I have been able to implement this functionality on a HTML table, but not a ng-grid.

Here is my HTML.

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"><!--ng-grid-->
 </div>
<table><!--HTML table-->
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Enabled</th>
  <th>Recurrence</th>
  <th>Type</th>
  <th>Protection</th>
  <th>Estimated Duration</th>
  <th>Priority</th>
  <th>Description</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr class="{{selectedClass(sched)}}" ng-click="selected($event,$index,sched)" ng-dblclick="openModal(sched)" ng-repeat="sched in scheduleData.scheduleList">
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button ng-click="openAddModal()">Add</button>
<button ng-click="openModal(getSelected())" ng-disabled="!singleSelection()">Edit</button>
<button ng-click="deleteSchedules()" ng-disabled="!somethingSelected()">Death to Schedules!</button>
<button ng-click="deleteAllSchedules()" ng-disabled="">Schedule Extermination!</button>
```

And here is my app.js

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  data: 'scheduleData.scheduleList',
  columnDefs: [
               ...                    
  ],
  enableCellSelection: true,
  enableSorting: true,
  enableColumnResize: true,
  enableColumnReordering: true,
  showGroupPanel: true,
  showColumnMenu: true,
  showFilter: true,
  showFooter: true
};
```

How would I go about implementing the same in ngGrid too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to do a few simple things...

Add the following to your gridOptions:

```
selectedItems: $scope.selections,
afterSelectionChange: function() {
    if($scope.selections != null){
        $scope.disabled = true;
    } else {
        $scope.disabled = false;
    }
 }
```

Use ng-disabled="disabled" on your elements and make sure that you set $scope.disabled = true to begin with.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fNemOQ?p=preview) for a better explanation

Comment: Let me try that, and let you know if I need a plunker..Thanks!

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't seem to work. Also, I'm not sure I understand the part where you say 'Use ng-disable="enable" on your elements.. I think its best if you can share a plunker!

Comment: Added the plunker...  I also made some other var name updates to have it make more logical sense.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the plunker..In my specific case, I do not want an additional column with checkbox. I want to be able to click any row and the Edit button should be enabled.

Comment: You can simply remove the checkbox piece ... its updated to no longer have that.