# Add Action Buttons to each row in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a ng-grid on my page which is used to display details.
Is there a way to add action buttons like edit or delete to my ng-grid?
Or any property in gridOpts that needs to be set so as to enable the edit and delete button.
Also, On click of the button how will I get the details of the row selected.
Here is the code for my ng-grid.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
            paginationPageSizes: [25, 50, 75],
            paginationPageSize: 25,
            multiSelect: false,
            enableCellEdit: true,
            enableRowSelection: true,
            enableColumnResize: true,
            enableCellSelection: true,
            columnDefs: [
              { name: 'Name' },
              { name: 'Description' },
              { name: 'FinalModuleWisePrivileges' },
              { name: 'FinalFunctionWisePrivileges' },
              { name: 'Active' },

            ]
        };
```

HTML:

I tried options like  enableCellEdit and enableRowSelection but they dont seem to work. 
Would this have to be done by using a loop when the grid is loaded?

I also tried to look at the following reference but it didn't help much.
[ng-grid how to enable Edit and Delete buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058477/ng-grid-how-to-enable-edit-and-delete-buttons?rq=1)

Edit: I added the following line of code to the gridOptions. This solves the temporary purpose but is there a neat way to do this?

```
cellTemplate: '<button ng-click="grid.appScope.editClicked(row)" ng-if="row.entity.Active == true">Edit</button>'
```

Answer (score 2):

you would need to add a column in ColumnDefs with a custom cell template..

```
columnDefs: [{ field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
             { field: 'description', displayName: 'Description'},
             { displayName: 'Actions', cellTemplate: 
             '<div class="grid-action-cell">'+
             '<a ng-click="deleteThisRow(row.entity);" >Delete</a></div>'}
            ]
    };
```

this example shows how to add custom Delete button

the example code is taken from [here](http://michelebustablog.azurewebsites.net/ng-grid-tip/)